# How to read pdf with multiple columns using iText?

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to read a pdf file which has 2 columns in a page. I want to output those 2 columns separately. How can I do that ? please give me an example.

Comment: maybe you can crop your page http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=101 and then read columns one by one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict iText's text extraction to a certain area by using a `RegionTextRenderFilter`. If you define a filter for each of your columns, you can extract them separately.

Here's an example of how to [restrict text extraction to an area](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279).